# Get JSON value which change everytime using php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a JSON file

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "data": {
    "files": {
      "4d7cc5ec-2aef-48ec-9ebf-f811d4c77a5d": {
        "mimetype": "video/mp4",
        "link": "https://example.com/video.mp4",
        "name": "video.mp4",
        "size": 348353594
      }
    },
    "uploadTime": 1618074643,
    "totalSize": 348353594
  }
}
```

Now the value `4d7cc5ec-2aef-48ec-9ebf-f811d4c77a5d` keeps changing every time the page is loaded. And I want to grab the value of `link`

My code is

```
//This one also not working. Gives 500 Internal Error.
$jsonfile = 'this is JSON file';
$json = json_decode($jsonfile);
$link = $json->data->files->4d7cc5ec-2aef-48ec-9ebf-f811d4c77a5d->link;
echo $link;
```

But the problem is `4d7cc5ec-2aef-48ec-9ebf-f811d4c77a5d` keeps changing every time. How do I then get the value of link using PHP?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is that the sole item in the `files` array, or are there any other items? How would the identification be done (like: is this always the first element?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `array_column()` as well as `true` as a second parameter to `json_decode()`

```
$json = json_decode($jsonfile,true);
$link = array_column($json['data']['files'],'link');
var_dump($link[0]);
```

sample output: https://3v4l.org/oSQvo

Note: In case `files` contains multiple dynamic values then `$link` will give you array of all links. you can apply `foreach()` to iterate and get individual links

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [array_keys()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) function would be perfect for your use.

It returns an array with all the keys from the array with numeric indexes. You could use something like:

```
$keys = array_keys($json->data->files);
$link = $keys[0];
```

Comment: @robert-wypiór Thank you for answering but it is not working.